# Issue to override Subscription Form FOSUser Bundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to override the Subscription Form of FOSUser bundle in a Symfony2 Project but I get this error :

Warning: Missing argument 1 for Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType::__construct(), called in C:\wamp\www\biblishare\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 3730 and defined

I search for the same issue but can't resolve it...

Here are my codes :

-app/config/config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Entity\Utilisateurs
    from_email:
            address:        contact@biblishare.com
            sender_name:  contact@biblishare.com
    registration:
        form:
            type: utilisateurs_utilisateurs_registration
```

-.../UtilisateursBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```
services:
    utilisateurs_utilisateurs.listener.authentication_success_handler:
        class: %utilisateurs_utilisateurs.listener.authentication_success_handler.class%
        public: false
        arguments:  ['@router', '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', '@security.context']

    utilisateurs_utilisateurs.registration.form.type:
        class: Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: utilisateurs_utilisateurs_registration }
```

and my form:

```
<?php

namespace Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    private $class;

    /**
     * @param string $class The User class name
     */
    public function __construct($class)
    {
        $this->class = $class;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // add your custom field
        $builder
            ->add('first_name', null, array('label' => 'Prénom :', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('family_name', null, array('label' => 'Nom :', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
                'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
            ))
        ;
    }

     public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => $this->class,
            'intention'  => 'registration',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'utilisateurs_utilisateurs_registration';
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help, I tried to erase the cache but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the user class as an argument to your service definition so that it will be called in the `__construct` method.

```
utilisateurs_utilisateurs.registration.form.type:
    class: Utilisateurs\UtilisateursBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
    arguments:
        - %fos_user.model.user.class%
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: utilisateurs_utilisateurs_registration }
```